# Wireless driver not detected by Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking, drivers

I've a problem in my wireless driver on windows 8. I bought a new X500L Asus laptop and installed windows 8 on it. However the driver CD I got with the laptop doesn't support my laptop. The CD says it's designed for Windows 8.1.

I tired finding Wireless driver model and finding driver online and installing and that hasn't worked either, the wireless driver is shown at the device manager as not installed. I tired live booting the computer with a live CD of Linux and that also doesn't pick up my wireless driver. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with the same problem with my Acer when I clean installed OS. Wireless driver on Acer website did not work. However, I suggest you use a free software called Driver Identifier. Here is the site http://driveridentifier.com/. I found it very useful. It is small and easy to use. You may find the description at the homepage. You might need internet connection and USB drive since you need to access to internet and download driver in other computer before copy it and install in your laptop. Hope this would help.